# Chart StackedBar Asp.net C# - Display by Month

Tags: asp.net, charts, bar-chart

I have a Stacked_Bar chart that is working just fine except am unable to display it by month.

```
 while (rdr.Read())
 {
 Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(rdr1["month"],0);
                    Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(Convert.ToInt32(rdr1["pass"]));
                    Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddY(Convert.ToInt32(rdr1["Fail"]));  
}
    The Database table columns are as follow
Month | Pass | Fail
Jan     55     2
Feb     10     3
...     ...    ...
...
```

Any idea how make it show the bars by month? 
Example: Every month like Jan the StackedBar will have the pass and fail stacked in it, then Feb will have Pass/ Fail stacked in it.